# Best practices for writing a latex document for web publishing (html)

Tags: html

I want to create a latex document that can be compiled as a single *pdf* file and also converted to a bunch of small *html* files for a web site.

How to automate the task of converting a latex document to many *html* files?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to generate separate files for chapters, sections, subsections. Try to use

```
htlatex filename "xhtml, 2"
```

this will break the html file at sectioning command on highest level, ie. `\section` when article class is used, or `\chapter` with book document class. Options `3` and `4` also exists, they will break document at second, resp. third sectioning level. Breaked files are hyperlinked, so it is easy to navigate amongst them.